# Json parsing in windows phone (C#)

Tags: windows-phone

I am new to Windows Phone development.I want to parse some data using json parsing.After

googling i find a number of example but I am not able to understand properly.I have follow 
a link

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.in/2012/01/json-deserialization-with-jsonnet.html

to do  json parsing But i am not able to show Storage ,Memory, ScreenSize in my List and my code is

```
    private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var w = new WebClient();
        Observable
          .FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(w, "DownloadStringCompleted")
          .Subscribe(r =>
          {
              var deserialized =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(r.EventArgs.Result);
              PhoneList.ItemsSource = deserialized;
          });
        w.DownloadStringAsync(
          new Uri("http://www.schaikweb.net/dotnetbyexample/JSONPhones1.txt"));
    }

}


public class Specs
{
    public string Storage { get; set; }
    public string Memory { get; set; }
    public string Screensize { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Specs Specs { get; set; }
}
```

}

Please Help me to solve this issue or any other sample for the same is also appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code seems ok, so if you aren't running in to any errors there might be an issue with your UI code or UI to data coupling.

You need to post the UI code to get some help with this I suspect.